# Why is this Set-Cookie header not setting a cookie?

Tags: cookies

Recently, I created a web server that can receive HTTP request and send out HTTP headers like this one:

> Set-Cookie: _ai_feed_reader_session=cmlDSW9NU3VMbEJBTEhvckpkQUh1OVVqRkh2R1NQK3pFb3EvQUpkTUZLK1NhYldrTmF5ZHFvd2pGSU9vNE9IcW4vQ1VHMmNpNkFJbW0vWlZLL2RVcE94SFNKbWYvcm9KL0ZrWjU3OEsxK3F0TGxjb1NMcDZnMmY5MWcrclVlZSs1T0JwYnpCOTc2aHpuOUcrRzNIU0hRPT0tLUFKNVN1OUdPdXZlT1VEWUhycU85Z0E9PQ%3D%3D--a9f08aaa2bc54af3c9b785f3c5d747f2b52d8257; count=1

But no actual cookie is being set. What is wrong with this Set-Cookie header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Set-Cookie doesn't handle multiple key-value pairs. Set-Cookie is supposed to handle a single key-value. If I write an invalid HTTP Header, obviously it'll get ignored.

This was how I was supposed to structure my HTTP Headers:

> Set-Cookie: _ai_feed_reader_session=cmlDSW9NU3VMbEJBTEhvckpkQUh1OVVqRkh2R1NQK3pFb3EvQUpkTUZLK1NhYldrTmF5ZHFvd2pGSU9vNE9IcW4vQ1VHMmNpNkFJbW0vWlZLL2RVcE94SFNKbWYvcm9KL0ZrWjU3OEsxK3F0TGxjb1NMcDZnMmY5MWcrclVlZSs1T0JwYnpCOTc2aHpuOUcrRzNIU0hRPT0tLUFKNVN1OUdPdXZlT1VEWUhycU85Z0E9PQ%3D%3D--a9f08aaa2bc54af3c9b785f3c5d747f2b52d8257
>
> Set-Cookie: count=1